# ExtJs 3.4 : Set label text and background color from Json data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, label

I have Json data as following.

```
{'dropPickStatus':[{ 'description' : 'Open', 'status' : '1', 'color' : '#6699FF' } , { 'description' : 'Hold', 'status' : '2', 'color' : '#FF9900' } , { 'description' : 'Cancel', 'status' : '3', 'color' : '#FF0000' } , { 'description' : 'Parked', 'status' : '4', 'color' : '#C0C0C0' } , { 'description' : 'Arrived', 'status' : '5', 'color' : '#FFFF00' } , { 'description' : 'Started', 'status' : '6', 'color' : '#993300' } , { 'description' : 'Completed', 'status' : '7', 'color' : '#009900' } , { 'description' : 'Night Out', 'status' : '8', 'color' : '#FFFFFF' } ]}
```

I am retrieving these data from postgresql database.

```
var statusStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields : [ {
    name : 'description'
}, {
    name : 'status'
}, {
    name : 'color'
} ],
root : 'dropPickStatus',
idProperty : 'status',
// autoDestroy : true,
autoLoad : true,

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "DropPickStatus"
}),
reader : {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'dropPickStatus'
},
});
```

And also I have extjs fieldset with eight labels.

```
{
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                layout : 'hbox',
                border : false,
                frame : false,
                defaults : {
                    layout : 'hbox',
                    labelAlign : 'top'
                },
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    forId : 'idOpen',
                    text : 'Open',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    // textAlign: 'center',
                    style : {
                        background : 'blue',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Hold',
                    forId : 'idHold',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'orange',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Cancel',
                    forId : 'idCancel',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'red',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Parked',
                    forId : 'idParked',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'gray',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    forId : 'idArrived',
                    text : 'Arrived',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'yellow',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Started',
                    forId : 'idStarted',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'purple',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Completed',
                    forId : 'idCompleted',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'green',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    text : 'Night Out',
                    forId : 'idNight Out',
                    width : 53,
                    height : 25,
                    style : {
                        background : 'Brown',
                        color : 'black'
                    }
                } ]
            }
```

I want to set label text and background color from my json data array. As an example, for my first label (open), need to set #6699FF as background color and 'Open' as text and so on.

**Edited Code:**

```
listeners : {
    load : function(me, records) {
        Ext.each(records,
                function(record) {
                    status = record.get('status');
                    if (status == '1') {
                        // lbOpen = Ext.getCmp('idOpen');
                        Ext.getCmp('idOpen').setText(record.get('description'));
                        alert(Ext.getCmp('idOpen').getEl());
                    } else if (status == '2') {
                        // lbHold = Ext.getCmp('idHold');
                        Ext.getCmp('idHold').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else if (status == '3') {
                        // lbCancel = Ext.getCmp('idCancel');
                        Ext.getCmp('idCancel').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else if (status == '4') {
                        // lbParked = Ext.getCmp('idParked');
                        Ext.getCmp('idParked').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else if (status == '5') {
                        // lbArrived = Ext.getCmp('idArrived');
                        Ext.getCmp('idArrived').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else if (status == '6') {
                        // lbStarted = Ext.getCmp('idStarted');
                        Ext.getCmp('idStarted').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else if (status == '7') {
                        // lbCompleted = Ext.getCmp('idCompleted');
                        Ext.getCmp('idCompleted').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    } else {
                        // lbNight = Ext.getCmp('idNightOut');
                        Ext.getCmp('idNightOut').setText(
                                record.get('description'));
                    }

                    // label.getEl().setStyle('background', record.get('color'));

                });
    }
}
```

**This set all the label text correctly. But when I try to set background color using label.getEl().setStyle('background', record.get('color')); my firebug console says getEl() is undefined**

How should I do that ? Please help me ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a listener to the store's `load` event. Find the corresponding label and modify the properties.  Here's an example

```
listeners: {
        load: function (me, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function (record) {
                //find the corresponding label with Ext.getCmp(id) or 
                //container.getComponent(itemId)
                label.getEl().setStyle('background', record.get('color'));
                label.setText(record.get('description'));
            });
        }
    }
```

I created a simple fiddle to demonstrate a working change to the label's text and style attribute.  You can find it [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qa)  The example is mocked up in **ExtJS 3.4**.

Comment: where should i put this listener ?

Comment: and how can i get each and every labe?

Comment: k.i should put this listener into mt store.But now, the problem is how should i get each label ?

Comment: it says getEl() is undefined ?

Comment: In my example I have the way to select the labels commented out (there is a couple of options) Were you able to query for the label and obtain the object in the store load? I can add example if needed.

Comment: What I want is it should be able to set corresponding background color and text. for label 'open' - text:Open, background Color : #6699FF, for label 'hold' - text:Hold, background Color : #FF9900

Comment: I can loop throgh my Json array using 'Ext.each(records, function (record)'. Then how should I iterate through mt labels ?

Comment: Please see my edited code. Now all the label texts are setting correctly. But the problem is about setting the background color. It says getEl() is undefined.

Comment: I added a fiddle working example to the answer, it is working as expected in the fiddle.